# Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.64.2 for expo sdkVersion 43.0.0. Use react-native@0.64.3

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on an expo project and everything is working fine, but I began to get a warning message when android is building as

```
Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.64.2 for expo sdkVersion 43.0.0. Use react-native@0.64.3
```

The app is still running fine but I don't how to fix this error yet and I want to know if it won't cause an issue later.

Comment: Explanation here https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-43-aa9b3c7d5541 from an update to this post dated @November 9th, 2021

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have tried to run `npx react-native upgrade 0.64.3` but it didn't work, I got this error

> info Fetching diff between v0.64.2 and v0.64.3... error Fetch request
> failed with status 404: 404: Not Found. error Failed to fetch diff for
> react-native@0.64.3. Maybe it's not released yet?

changing the version of `react-native` manually in the `package.json` and run `expo install`  worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I use the `expo doctor` command it allows diagnose issues with the project.

I would recommend using the `expo upgrade` command. It upgrades the project packages and config for the given SDK version.

More to find [here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/#info).

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue. Basically it's telling you should use a higher version of your react-native. I solved it just by updating it to the specified version.

```
npx react-native upgrade 0.64.3
```

More info [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading).
Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

If as in my case one need a specific version of react-native, let's say older because some legacy dependencies in a particular project that for some reason can't be upgrade, then change the version in the package.json won't work.

What worked as the cli suggested is to use:

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

That installed the correct lower version of react-native

Comment: i had this error : Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.69.1 for expo sdkVersion 45.0.0. Use react-native@0.68.2 , expo doctor --fix-dependencies help me too, thanks

Answer (score 2):

To find out actual problems run this command :

```
expo doctor
```

To solve all problems regarding package conflicts run this command:

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

Use **sudo** on Unix based OS if you have permission issue to run those commands.

Comment: Sudo is for admin right on unix system, has nothing to do with the question in the topic.

Comment: expo doctor & expo doctor --fix-dependencies are enough but sometimes its needs sudo on unix if the user do not have proper permission.

By the way, I updated the answer

Comment: Solution worked for me, no issues

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error, I used the below command:

```
npm install react-native-clean-project --save-dev
```

It is a library that allows us to resolve conflicts.
This library is added to your dependencies.

This handles the problem and if it is not the case add this command:

```
react-native clean-project-auto
```